# Would you exchange your queen for two rooks?

Tags: strategy, exchange

The question is general, not pinned to a particular position. But for example here is a self-fabricated position:

```
[FEN "6k1/p4ppp/1r1r2n1/1N6/P7/3Q4/2P3PP/1K6 w - - 0 1"]

1. Qxd6 Rxd6 2. Nxd6
```

Comment: Probably not the best example because of the tactic it includes. White HAS to exchange the queen for the rooks here, because if he just moves it away, black will win the pinned knight with ...a6 (White cannot make a credible counter-threat with his queen move because the black knight covers a back rank mate and the rooks defend each other).

Comment: The question isn't really answerable in the abstract. You'd exchange my queen even for a pawn if it led to immediate checkmate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Only a lonely queen fears two rooks

Source: *The wisest things ever said about chess* by GM Soltis, paraphrasing Fischer.

The point behind the quote is that if there are more pieces on the board, the queen tends to outperform the rooks. If there are just pawns (no pieces) then the rook side tends to be better.

> Fischer showed that when there are minor pieces present - even just one pair - the queen has no reason to fear the rooks